# How to close the frame when I click the exit button?

Tags: processing

In my processing project, I create another frame with the function below:

```
ExtraOptionsFrame addExtraOptionsFrame(String theName, int theWidth, int theHeight)
{
  extraOptionsFrame_parent_java_frame = new Frame(theName);
  ExtraOptionsFrame of = new ExtraOptionsFrame(this, theWidth, theHeight);
  extraOptionsFrame_parent_java_frame.add(of);
  of.init();
  extraOptionsFrame_parent_java_frame.setTitle(theName);
  extraOptionsFrame_parent_java_frame.setSize(of.w, of.h);
  extraOptionsFrame_parent_java_frame.setLocation(100, 100);
  extraOptionsFrame_parent_java_frame.setResizable(false);
  extraOptionsFrame_parent_java_frame.setVisible(true);
  return of;
}
```

But when I click the exit button of the new frame, I can't close it. I am wondering maybe I should add some code. Someone please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to search on the processing site. The issue may be happening elsewhere in your code.

Comment: You'll have much better luck if you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a disconnected snippet. Note that this should **not** be your entire project, just enough for us to run your program for ourselves!